# Sending post and passing address as route

Tags: laravel, routes, laravelcollective

I have the routes

```
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@index');
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login');
```

the get to display my my login screen and the post for submission.

This is my controller login

```
 public function index(){
       return view('Login.index');
 }

 public function login(Request $request)
 {

 }
```

How can I get my form to send requests to this controller via the route? I'm trying this way

```
{!! Form::open(['id'=>'Formulario','route' => ['login.login'],'class'=>'form']) !!}
```

but the following error occurs

> Route [login.login] not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Name the route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes) to make it work:

```
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login.login');
```

Or:

```
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'login.login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@login']);
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, when I use Route :: resource ('/ client', clientcontroller); and do the client.store route it works without me needing to put the name, is it because of the resource?

Comment: @Bruno yes, `::resource()` registers route names for you. Run `php artisan route:list` command to see all registered routes with their names.